# Create array with javascript from text string and manipulate the data to suit your needs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have text string patern (_code: value, _code: value, _code: value, _code: value, )

It can be like this _cvgx12: volvo, _ccc325: hello my name is andrius, _asc789: sport, _code: This is example of text string,

I need create array from this string. In array i want only include value.

myarray=["value","value","value","value","value",]

value can be anything  example

myarray=["volvo","hello my name is andrius","sport","value","Sackoverflow",]

Im trying approach like this

Split ext to array myarray= mytext.split(' '); // I dot think this value is right

Also im removing code part like this:

```
        filtered = myarray.filter(function(el, index) {

                return index % 2 === 1;
              });
```

Im geting array but i cant use spaces between words

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: `"Sackoverflow"` made me laugh, good one

Comment: So where did you get stuck, precisely? How did you own attempts work, or fail? What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to parse the string in some manner**. Exactly how fancy you get with this is up to you: I don't know the exact grammar you're going for, but depending on how you do things, this could be really simple or quite complex. I'm making the following assumptions and inferences:

- The actual delimiter between code-value pairs is the comma (","), and the actual delimiter between a code and its value is a colon (":")
- Codes can't contain colons, but values can.
- Codes don't need to start with an underscore (though they can).
- There is no way to escape colons and commas.
- Leading and trailing whitespace is ignored for codes and values, but whitespace inside codes and values is preserved.
- Empty items (for example, resulting from a dangling "," at the end of the string) are ignored.
- Multiple items with the same code ARE allowed.

With those rules in mind, here's my solution:

```
function parse(input) {
    return String(input).split(',').reduce(function (result, item) {
        var parts;
        if (item.trim().length > 0) {
            parts = item.split(':');
            result.push(parts.slice(1).join(':').trim());
        }
        return result;
    }, []);
};
```

The first split (in Line 2) gets us our code-value pairs. We then reduce() over the array of pairs, starting from the empty array we create on Line 9, to get the final result.

The check on item.trim().length in Line 4 ensures that we ignore empty items (like the one that would be created by your dangling comma).

In Line 5 we split on ':', but then in Line 6, we rejoin all parts after the first one. This ensures that any values in colons remain in the string. If we didn't do this, then anything after the first colon would be lost.

Lastly, the push in Line 6 ensures that the split item goes into the array.

[Here's a JSFiddle which applies this code to your examples.](http://jsfiddle.net/The_Spooniest/j0a5o9hr/) If you decide that you need to return a different kind of object, you can do it by modifying the function and value passed to `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
var pattern = {
   "_cvgx12": "volvo",
   "_ccc325": "hello my name is andrius",
   "_asc789": "sport",
   "_code": "This is example of text string"
}

var myArray = [];
for(var prop in pattern){
    myArray.push(pattern[prop]);
}
```

Very simple, very crude, but works

Comment: I think pattern is a text, not an object.

Comment: Oh, well if that's the case, then it's the job of a RegEx, and for that to work, strict rules need applied. I'll let the OP clarify on that..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how strict you want to be, the following would be a starting point:

```
str
    .replace(/^\(|\)$/)               // remove parens
    .split(',')                       // split on commas
    .map(function(entry) {            // then for each entry
        return entry.split(':')[1];   // split on colon and return 2nd half
    })
;
```

Perhaps some trimming should be added.